# How can I get invited user's id?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I want to add a function on my facebook application that enable to check user ids which is invited by certain user.
e.g. 
A invited B, then insert id of B relating with id of A to Database only for the first request.
(It doesn't matter whether B will accept the request or not)
I will add up how many people was invited by A and give some items according to the count on my game application. 
Something like that.

I'm not sure how can I make it.

Comment: Can you provide your script that you use to enable A to invite B?

Comment: Actually I cannot describe it because its not our script, but belongs to other. What I could gain from the program is request_ids. e.g. 199113303448845,194671267223651,195892490439891

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get solution by myself.
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST_ID?ACCESS_TOKEN;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);